# Auto Send Emails Depending on Dropdown Menu Choice in Google Form

Tags: google-apps-script, google-forms

I am a complete beginner when it comes to code and script. I'm trying to get my form to send and email to specific people depending on a response on a drop down menu.

Example: Pete is working on Project A, so they select Project A on a drop down menu asking what project they are working on. 
If Pete selects Project A, I need a response to go to Persons A,B and C.
Now if Jessica is working on Project B, I need a response to go to persons A,B and D

Is this possible? Did I explain this properly? Am I completly dense and it's simple?

Comment: It is possible.

Comment: Is there a post already that explains this?

Comment: I recommend starting [here](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/) and also take a look at [this](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/).

Answer (score 0):

I offer this simple example just to give you a start.  Take a close look at it.  Use the online documentation to figure out what it does.  In the G-Suite Services you'll find information about Gmail and how to use it.  Plus there are numerous examples on this site pertaining to email.

Google Script:

```
function getSelectOptions(){
  var ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var sh=ss.getSheetByName('Selections')
  var rg=sh.getDataRange();
  var selections=[];
  var vA=rg.getValues();
  for (var i=0;i<vA.length;i++){
    selections.push(vA[i][0]);
  }
  return selections;
}

function getEmailsForChoice(choice){
  var ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var sh=ss.getSheetByName('Selections')
  var rg=sh.getDataRange();
  var vA=rg.getValues();
  for (var i=0;i<vA.length;i++){
    if(choice==vA[i][0]){
      var emails=Utilities.formatString('%s;%s;%s',vA[i][1],vA[i][2],vA[i][3]);
      break;
    }                 
  }
  return emails;
}

function showMyDialog(){
  var ui=HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('choices')
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showModelessDialog(ui, 'Choices');
}
```

choices.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <base target="_top">
  <script>
    window.onload=function(){
        google.script.run
          .withSuccessHandler(updateSelect)
          .getSelectOptions();
      }

     function updateSelect(vA){
      var select = document.getElementById("sel1");
      //select.options.length = 0; 
      for(var i=0;i<vA.length;i++)
      {
        select.options[i] = new Option(vA[i],vA[i]);
      }
    }  

    function savSelect(){
      var selected=document.getElementById('sel1').value;
      google.script.run
      .withSuccessHandler(function(emails){
        console.log(emails);
        document.getElementById('emails').innerHTML='Send Emails to the following: '+emails;
      })
      .getEmailsForChoice(selected);
    }
    console.log('My Code');
  </script>
  </head>
  <body>
  <div id="emails"></div>
  <select id="sel1" onChange="savSelect();"></select>
  </body>
  </html>
```

This is what my spreadsheet looks like:

[image]